# Why can I print this treating as a reference and treating it as a scalar?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, scalar

In the following perl snippet:

```
my $a1 = [ qw(rock pop musical) ];  
my $b1 = [ qw( mystery action drama )];  
my $c1 = [ qw( biography novel periodical)];  

my @a2d = (  
    $a1,  
    $b1,  
    $c1  
);
```

The `@a2d` is an array which contain references to arrays.
My question is why the following print the same thing (`musical`)?:

```
print ${$a2d[0]}[2],"\n";  
print $a2d[0][2],"\n";
```

I expected the second to print ARRAY or give an error since the elements of the array are refences

Answer (score 10):

The `$a2d[0]` is an array reference. We can take this array reference and print out the 3rd entry:

```
my $ref = $a2d[0];
say ${ $ref }[2];
say $ref->[2];
```

These forms are equivalent. Now, we can do away with that intermediate variable, and get:

```
say ${ $a2d[0] }[2];
say $a2d[0]->[2];
```

If the dereference operator `->` occurs between two subscripts, then it may be omitted as a shortcut:

```
say $a2d[0][2];
```

The arrow may be omitted when the left subscript is `[...]` or `{...}` and the right subscript it `[...]`, `{...}` or `(...)`.

This is also explained in [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Arrow-Rule), which goes through these considerations in more depth. Reading that document should clear up many questions.

Answer (score 9):

The dereference is implied when you tack on indexes.

```
$a2d[0][2]
```

is short for

```
${ $a2d[0] }[2]
```

aka

```
$a2d[0]->[2]
```

Rather than giving a syntax error, Perl provides a useful shortcut for a common operation.

Other examples: `$aoa[$i][$j]`, `$aoh[$i]{$k}`, `$hoa{$k}[$i]` and `$hoh{$k1}{$k2}`.